# R - how to speed a for loop with vectorised operations. Pratical problem

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I've tried to create a minimal example, sorry.
Is there a way to speed the process?
My `procedures` table has 4M rows. I am processing for 15 hours and it has populate only 1.5M rows.
Maybe using mutate, I don't know.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

```
frequencies <- tibble(
  id = 1:3,
  date_hour_initial = c(
    dmy_hms('01/01/2020 13:00:00'),
    dmy_hms('01/01/2020 15:00:00'),
    dmy_hms('02/01/2020 20:00:00')
  ),
  date_hour_final= c(
    dmy_hms('01/01/2020 18:00:00'),
    dmy_hms('01/01/2020 22:00:00'),
    dmy_hms('03/01/2020 05:00:00')
  ),
  id_person = c("1", "2", "2"),
  type_service = c("1", "3", "4")
) %>%
  mutate(
    intervalo = interval(
      date_hour_initial,
      date_hour_final
    )
  )


procedures <- tibble(
  id = 1:3,
  date_hour = c(
    dmy_hms('01/01/2020 17:00:00'),
    dmy_hms('01/01/2020 22:00:00'),
    dmy_hms('03/01/2020 03:00:00')
  ),
  id_person = c("1", "1", "2")
)
```

```
procedures$type_service <- vector(
  "character",
  nrow(procedures)
  )


for(i in 1:nrow(procedures)) {

frequencies %>%
    filter(
      procedures$date_hour[i] %within% intervalo,
      id_person == procedures$id_person[i]
    ) %>% pull(type_service) %>% unique() -> response

  if(length(response) == 1){
    procedures$type_service[i] <- response
  } else {
    procedures$type_service[i] <- NA_character_
  }

}
```

Comment: You aren't doing any grouping or anything that requires `dplyr`. Have you looked at using base R for this?

Comment: @cory, but `base` R can also do grouping operations.

Comment: @cory I am creating a new column. Usually i do this with `dplyr::mutate`. Maybe there is a way to encapsulate all of my operations in a mutate call. I could not think of anything.

Comment: I think you want an interval merge between your two frames. Look at the data.table function `foverlaps` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.8/topics/foverlaps.

Comment: Possibly very similar problem to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694729/r-merge-2-dataframes-with-timestamp-between

Comment: You can also try performing this inside a foreach loop and parallelizing it. Here is some documentation. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf

Comment: @Parfait awesome, post your base R solution. I'll look forward to seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using non-equi join in `data.table`:

```
procedures[, type_service := 
    frequencies[procedures, on=.(id_person, date_hour_initial<=date_hour, date_hour_final>=date_hour),
        by=.EACHI, if (length(x.type_service) == 1L) x.type_service]$V1
]
```

output:

```
   id           date_hour id_person type_service
1:  1 2020-01-01 17:00:00         1            1
2:  2 2020-01-01 22:00:00         1         <NA>
3:  3 2020-01-03 03:00:00         2            4
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
frequencies <- data.table(id = 1:3,
    date_hour_initial = as.POSIXct(c('01/01/2020 13:00:00','01/01/2020 15:00:00','02/01/2020 20:00:00'), format="%d/%m/%Y %T"),
    date_hour_final= as.POSIXct(c('01/01/2020 18:00:00','01/01/2020 22:00:00','03/01/2020 05:00:00'), format="%d/%m/%Y %T"),
    id_person = c("1", "2", "2"),
    type_service = c("1", "3", "4"))

procedures <- data.table(id = 1:3, 
    date_hour = as.POSIXct(c('01/01/2020 17:00:00','01/01/2020 22:00:00','03/01/2020 03:00:00'), format="%d/%m/%Y %T"),
    id_person = c("1", "1", "2"))
```

My guess is that this will take around a min for 4 mio rows?

Comment: I did manage to achieve the result in 2.76 seconds with data.table::foverlaps().
But your solution is cool too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr solution without using loops:

```r
library(tidyverse)

 left_join(frequencies, procedures, by = "id_person") %>%
  mutate(type_service = ifelse(date_hour %within% intervalo, type_service.x, NA)) %>% 
  select(id = id.y, date_hour, id_person, type_service) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(type_service) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(id)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(id)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      id date_hour           id_person type_service
#>   <int> <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>       
#> 1     1 2020-01-01 17:00:00 1         1           
#> 2     2 2020-01-01 22:00:00 1         NA          
#> 3     3 2020-01-03 03:00:00 2         4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the fuzzy join package.  First step is split the frequency and procedure dataframes by person Id.  This is dividing the large problem into many smaller problem.  I did not add any error checking to ensure there is a corresponding match between the person_id between the 2 data frames.

Once the data frames are split, loop through each person id and using the `left_fuzzy_join` function to match "data_hour" in procedures and the "interval" in frequencies

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
#divide and conquer
#split the data frame down to list by person_id
sfreq<-split(frequencies, frequencies$id_person)
sprocedures <- split(procedures, procedures$id_person)

library(fuzzyjoin)
#define function for the matching
matfun<-function(x, y){
  x %within% y
}

#define empty answer list
answer<-list()
#loop thru all of the split groups
for (id in names(sfreq)) {
  print(id)
  #perfrom a fuzzy join with data_hour in procedures and the interval in frequencies
  answer[[id]]<-fuzzy_left_join(sprocedures[[id]], sfreq[[id]],  by= c("date_hour" ="intervalo"), match_fun=matfun)
}

#Combine all of the subsets into the final answer
finalanswer<-bind_rows(answer)
```